# How to open device Settings instead of App specific settings?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, url, settings

I had been using the following code to take the user to Device Settings page to turn ON the internet.

```
guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Settings")
            else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl)
        {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Back to app From Settings: \(success)") // Prints true
                })
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
            }
        }
```

But Apple has rejected my update because of using this code stating the reason as below,

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>   To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the "prefs:root" or "App-Prefs:root" URL scheme.

So i have now used the following code to avoid this rejection. But this code takes me to APP SPECIFIC SETTINGS page and not the general settings.

```
guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }
```

So now how do i tweak this code to navigate to GENERAL settings?

Comment: Using `App-Prefs:` is enough, you don't need the `root=Settings` part to open general settings

Comment: "*So now how do i tweak this code to navigate to GENERAL settings?*" - you don't. Apple rejected your attempt for a reason.

Comment: @mag_zbc Is it under Apple's guidelines to use the App-Prefs: ?

Comment: @Mano This is a private API. Do not use this `URL`. Apple’s rejection reason is pretty clear.